# Disable/Enable FK for REFERENCES

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, foreign-keys

I am trying to automate a process to disable and enable foreign keys so I can delete "bad data".

Below is an example of one of our application schemas. I found this Tom Kyte query to show the relationships between some tables.

```
create table c ( x NUMBER, 
CONSTRAINT c_pk PRIMARY KEY(x)
);

create table c1 ( x NUMBER, 
CONSTRAINT c1_pk PRIMARY KEY(x),
CONSTRAINT c1_fk FOREIGN KEY (x) REFERENCES c(x));

create table c2 ( x NUMBER, 
CONSTRAINT c2_pk PRIMARY KEY(x),
CONSTRAINT c2_fk FOREIGN KEY (x) REFERENCES c2(x));

create table c3 ( x NUMBER, 
CONSTRAINT c3_pk PRIMARY KEY(x),
CONSTRAINT c3_fk FOREIGN KEY (x) REFERENCES c2(x));

create table c4 ( x NUMBER, 
CONSTRAINT c4_pk PRIMARY KEY(x),
CONSTRAINT c4_fk FOREIGN KEY (x) REFERENCES c2(x));

 /* child/parent relationship */
with cte as (
  select table_name, constraint_type, constraint_name, r_constraint_name,
    max(decode(constraint_type,'R',1,0)) over(partition by table_name) is_r
  from user_constraints 
  where constraint_type in ('P', 'U', 'R')
)
, child_parent as (
  select distinct s.table_name child, d.table_name parent, d.constraint_type
  from (select * from cte where constraint_type = 'R' or is_r = 0) s
  left join cte d
    on s.r_constraint_name = d.constraint_name
    and s.table_name != d.table_name
)
select level lvl, child, parent, constraint_type
from child_parent
start with parent is null
connect by parent = prior child
order siblings by parent, child;

LVL CHILD   PARENT  CONSTRAINT_TYPE
1   C    -   - 
2   C1  C   P
1   C2   -   - 
2   C3  C2  P
2   C4  C2  P
```

I have the following code, which will disable and enable FK's. I know this can be merged into one piece of code(procedure, which accepts parameter???) but I haven't gotten to that point yet.

As you can see from the output below it disables and enables ALL FK'S in the schema where I only want code that will do it for one set of references.

For example, if I pass in table "C" my code should only disable and enable FK C1_FK. If I pass in table "C2" my code should only disable and enable C3_FK, C4_FK

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance to all who answer. Note if there is a better way to code this solution I'm open to all suggestions

```
/* disable foreign keys */

DECLARE 
  sql_command        varchar2(500);
BEGIN
    FOR r IN (
        SELECT '"' || a.owner
                    || '"."'
                    || a.table_name
                    || '"' AS full_table_name,
                a.constraint_name
            FROM user_constraints a
            JOIN user_constraints b
                ON ( a.r_constraint_name = b.constraint_name
                    AND a.r_owner = b.owner )
            WHERE a.constraint_type = 'R'
                AND a.status = 'ENABLED'
            ORDER BY 1 )  
    LOOP    
        sql_command := 'alter table ' || r.full_table_name || ' disable constraint ' || r.constraint_name;
                       dbms_output.put_line(sql_command);
     execute immediate sql_command;      
    END LOOP ;
END ;
/

Statement processed.
alter table "XXX"."C1" disable constraint C1_FK
alter table "XXX"."C2" disable constraint C2_FK
alter table "XXX"."C3" disable constraint C3_FK
alter table "XXX"."C4" disable constraint C4_FK

DECLARE 
  sql_command        varchar2(500);
BEGIN
    FOR r IN (
        SELECT '"' || a.owner
                    || '"."'
                    || a.table_name
                    || '"' AS full_table_name,
                a.constraint_name
            FROM user_constraints a
            JOIN user_constraints b
                ON ( a.r_constraint_name = b.constraint_name
                    AND a.r_owner = b.owner )
            WHERE a.constraint_type = 'R'
                AND a.status = 'DISABLED'
            ORDER BY 1 )  
    LOOP    
        sql_command := 'alter table ' || r.full_table_name || ' enable constraint ' || r.constraint_name;
                       dbms_output.put_line(sql_command);
     execute immediate sql_command;      
    END LOOP ;
END ;
/

Statement processed.
alter table "XXX"."C1" enable constraint C1_FK
alter table "XXX"."C2" enable constraint C2_FK
alter table "XXX"."C3" enable constraint C3_FK
alter table "XXX"."C4" enable constraint
```

Comment: why not filter a.table_name = 'C1' then you wpould only have the constraints of C!

Comment: The whole point of foreign key constraints is to protect your data integrity so you don't delete things you shouldn't delete and create orphans. If you disable the constraints, you bypass this protection and open yourself up to issues. What's the point of having them at all if you keep disabling them? If the volume is small, leave the constraints alone. If it's huge (data warehouse proportions), then simply drop the FKs and leave them off, you shouldn't be using foreign key constraints in such an environment.

Comment: @nbk I'm looking for a generic solution that would work in any situation so I don't want any hardcoded values.

Comment: pass the table name to a procdure and use that, else where should the alghorithm know that you want C1

Comment: You may alter constraint as initially deferred and do anything you want with no data disruption. When you are done - commit and receive all the errors if any. It would be much safer than enabling and disabling

Comment: @astentx that would require a lot more additional code and testing. I will try and implement nbk wrapper suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to delete rows from a parent table you can't disable & re-enable the foreign keys to it. In general there will still be rows in the child tables pointing to the (now missing) parent row.

So either you need to

- Also delete from the child tables/set their FK columns to `null`
- Reenable the foreign keys with the `novalidate` option

If it's "bad data" you're trying to remove from the parent, you almost certainly want to remove it from the children as well. In which case you need to run deletes/updates on these child tables too.

Which makes the process of enabling/disabling the FKs a rather wasted effort. Just run the DML through the tables from the children up to the parents and it "just works" while leaving the FKs enabled.

If you want to make this process easier, you can declare the foreign keys as `on delete [cascade | set null]`. This automatically propagates any deletes from the parent table to the children.

**Be very careful setting `on delete cascade`. With this it's very easy to run a `delete` on a small lookup table and end up wiping out huge amounts of data!**

For example:

```
create table par1 ( c1 int constraint p1_pk primary key );
create table par2 ( c2 int constraint p2_pk primary key );

create table chld (
  c1 
    constraint chld_fk_1 references par1 
    on delete cascade,
  c2 
    constraint chld_fk_2 references par2
    on delete set null
);

insert into par1 values ( 1 );
insert into par1 values ( 2 );
insert into par2 values ( 1 );
insert into par2 values ( 2 );

insert into chld values ( 1, 1 );
insert into chld values ( 2, 2 );

select * from chld;
/*
        C1         C2
---------- ----------
         1          1
         2          2
*/

commit;

delete par1 where c1 = 1;
delete par2 where c2 = 2;

select * from chld;
/*
        C1         C2
---------- ----------
         2 <null>    
*/
```